# can't find build folder and apk on gradle:0.11, for my android build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

This might be very basic question.
I'm building my Android app with Gradle and i get success build but i can't find the build file-the .apk.

So the problem begone with adding the new android sdk than I added

```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
```

to the gradle file, also before I did had a problem with something like: missing zipalign. Now after running `gradle clean build` the build folder where all gradle builds are stored was deleted and I can't find where are the new gradle builds.

this is the end of the console output:

```
:pager-indicator-lib:assembleDebug
:pager-indicator-lib:assembleRelease
:pager-indicator-lib:assemble
:pager-indicator-lib:lint
Ran lint on variant debug: 12 issues found
Ran lint on variant release: 12 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:/home/marko/work/MyProject/myproject-android/pager-indicator-lib/build/outputs/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to /home/marko/work/MyProject/myproject-android/pager-indicator-lib/build/outputs/lint-results.xml
:pager-indicator-lib:check
:pager-indicator-lib:build


   BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The apk files are stored under the build directory in each module:

```
<module>/build/outputs/apk
```

However, the "outputs" directory is not displayed in the project view in Android Studio.

You must leave Android Studio to see the "outputs" folder.  Right click on the "build" directory in the module for the app you are searching for and chose the "Reveal in Finder" or "Reveal in Explorer" option.  The "outputs" folder should then be visible.

Comment: Thanks, The problem was that I wasn't running the script in the project folder but one level up